# Why is the upcoming chat events displaying past events?

Tags: feature-request, chat, chat-event

I was recently browsing the SO chatrooms, and was surprised when **I noticed that I could join an upcoming event that happened in the past.**

[image]

After further investigation, I noticed a message on the chat event page that it was *Currently running, ends in 9 hours.*

**That's really confusing.** Can we change the "15 hours ago" to one of the following (or something similar)?:

- *Started 15 hours ago*
- *9 hours left*
- *15/24 hours completed*

Additionally, it might make sense to rename "upcoming events" to "current and upcoming events." The problem with that is it significantly reduces the amount of usable space to display actual events. **How could this be solved?**